# React pass increment data to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I know this is a really basic thing, but for some reason my mind is just running a blank right now on what Im doing wrong. So basically all Im trying to do is click a button and show the value go up by 1 everytime I click it. Im trying to have my Increment button as a child and then pass the new value up to the parent.

This is my app.js (parent)

```
import React from 'react';
import IncrementButton from './increment-button';

export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        count: 0
    };
}

increment(){
    this.setState({
        count:this.state.count+1
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="parent">
            <div className="count">
                Number of clicks: {this.state.count}
            </div>
            <IncrementButton count={this.increment}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

This is my increment-button component

```
import React from 'react';

export default function IncrementButton(props) {

return <button onClick={() => props.count}>Increment</button>;
}
```

Right now Im not seeing any change for "Number of clicks:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`props.count` is a function, invoke it.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function IncrementButton(props) {

return <button onClick={() => props.count()}>Increment</button>;
}
```

Also for your app.js, you need to bind the scope for `this.increment`, so use arrow function instead.

```
import React from 'react';
import IncrementButton from './increment-button';

export default class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        count: 0
    };
}

increment(){
    this.setState({
        count:this.state.count+1
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="parent">
            <div className="count">
                Number of clicks: {this.state.count}
            </div>
            <IncrementButton count={() => this.increment()}/>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to invoke props.count() before, but it didnt work. My issue was I just forgot to bind it. Thank you so much, that did it.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You gotto call the `count()` since it is a function -

```
<button onClick={() => props.count()}>Increment</button>;
```